# Java XML parser blocks (very unusual and strange!)

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xslt

I have a very strange case:

I tried to parse several XHTML-conform websites using default Java XML parser(s). The test blocks during parsing (not during downloading).

Can this be a bug, or does the parser tries to download additional referenced resources during parsing (which would be a "nice" anti-feature)?

With simple data, it works. (TEST1)
With complex data, it blocks. (TEST2)
(I tried `en.wikipedia.org` and `validator.w3.org`)

When blocking occurs, CPU is idle.

Tested with JDK6 and JDK7, same results.

Please see test case, source is ready for copy + paste + run.

### Source

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class _XmlParsingBlocks {

  private static Document parseXml(String data)
      throws Exception {
    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    DocumentBuilder b = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    DOMResult out = new DOMResult(b.newDocument());
    t.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(data)), out);
    return (Document) out.getNode();
  }

  private static byte[] streamToByteArray(InputStream is)
      throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    for (;;) {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
      int count = is.read(buffer);
      if (count == -1) {
        is.close();
        break;
      }
      baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
  }

  private static void test(byte[] data)
      throws Exception {
    String asString = new String(data, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    System.out.println("===== PARSING STARTED =====");
    Document doc = parseXml(asString);
    System.out.println("===== PARSING ENDED =====");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws Exception {
    {
      System.out.println("********** TEST 1");
      test("<html>test</html>".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    {
      System.out.println("********** TEST 2");
      URL url = new URL("http://validator.w3.org/");
      URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      byte[] data = streamToByteArray(is);
      System.out.println("===== DOWNLOAD FINISHED =====");

      test(data);
    }
  }

}
```

### Output

```
********** TEST 1
===== PARSING STARTED =====
===== PARSING ENDED =====
********** TEST 2
===== DOWNLOAD FINISHED =====
===== PARSING STARTED =====

[here it blocks]
```

Comment: well, for one thing, it's almost always a bad idea to convert xml bytes to xml chars.  unless you really know what you are doing, you have a high likelihood of breaking the xml.  so, first step is to parse the xml using and inputstream, not a String.

Comment: did you actually look at the xml?  does it include other documents?  did you attach a debugger to see where the code is blocked?  (or dump the current stack traces).

Comment: I did look at XML. Yes, it's a bad idea to convert something to String by assuming an encoding, but this isn't the point here. It's only a test to isolate and reproduce strange behavior. (BTW, encoding of tested website is really UTF-8)

Comment: If in doubt, debug it out. Or use jstack to get a stack trace. Should give you a hint of what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3C have in the last few months started blocking requests for common DTDs such as the XHTML DTD - they can't cope with the traffic generated. If you're not using a proxy server that caches the DTDs, you will need to use an EntityResolver or catalog to redirect the references to a local copy.

Comment: Thanks! When Michael Kay himself tells this, I believe ;) -- I have already decided to use DTDs from Linux packages (`xhtml-dtd` and `html-dtd`).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the page you downloaded, it contains some more `http:` URLs.

This is the start:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

I could imagine that the XML parser is trying to download the referenced DTD here, to be able to validate the XML content.

Try to add the preamble to your simple document, or try to let it away from your complex one, to see if this changes something.

Switch the parser to non-validating, and look if this helps. (Alternatively, there are some options to configure how the parser behaves - `setURIResolver` looks good, for example.)

Comment: Indeed, the doctype header causes TEST 1 to block. Setting URI resolver to a custom one which just throws Error in any case, doesn't help (and no Error is thrown, which indicates that the resolver isn't used). -- Do you happen to know, how to switch to a non-validating parser? `setAttribute` documentation doesn't contain possible keys.

Comment: Ok, setting to non-validating doesn't work either. I tried parsing with `DocumentBuilderFactory` instead of `TransformerFactory`. I set everything to false, didn't help, blocks anyway :( -- `df.setValidating(false); df.setXIncludeAware(false); df.setCoalescing(false); df.setExpandEntityReferences(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Solution: prefetch (or better: use offline stored) DTDs for a custom `EntityResolver`.

When it is expected, that no external XML entities are used (such as `&nbsp;`), an empty `InputSource` can be returned, see inner enum. Otherwise, a prepared mapping of `DTD URI -> bytearray` can be used to prevent downloading DTDs online.

### Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.annotation.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public final class PrefetchedEntityResolver
    implements EntityResolver {

  /**
  * NOTE: {@see #RETURN_NULL} seems to cause default behavior
  * (which is: downloading the DTD);
  * use {@see #RETURN_EMPTY_DATA} to ensure "offline" behavior
  * (which could lead to entity parsing errors).
  */
  public static enum NoMatchBehavior {

    THROW_EXCEPTION, RETURN_NULL, RETURN_EMPTY_DATA;
  }

  private final SortedMap<String, byte[]> prefetched;
  private final NoMatchBehavior noMatchBehavior;

  public PrefetchedEntityResolver(NoMatchBehavior noMatchBehavior,
      @Nullable SortedMap<String, byte[]> prefetched) {
    this.noMatchBehavior = noMatchBehavior;
    this.prefetched = new TreeMap<>(prefetched == null
        ? Collections.<String, byte[]>emptyMap() : prefetched);
  }

  @Override
  public InputSource resolveEntity(String name, String uri)
      throws SAXException, IOException {
    byte[] data = prefetched.get(uri);
    if (data == null) {
      switch (noMatchBehavior) {
      case RETURN_NULL:
        return null;
      case RETURN_EMPTY_DATA:
        return new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{}));
      case THROW_EXCEPTION:
        throw new SAXException("no prefetched DTD found for: " + uri);
      default:
        throw new Error("unsupported: " + noMatchBehavior.toString());
      }
    }

    return new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
  }

}
```

### Usage

```
public static Document parseXml(byte[] data)
    throws Exception {
  DocumentBuilderFactory df = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  df.setValidating(false);
  df.setXIncludeAware(false);
  df.setCoalescing(false);
  df.setExpandEntityReferences(false);

  DocumentBuilder b = df.newDocumentBuilder();
  b.setEntityResolver(new PrefetchedEntityResolver(
      PrefetchedEntityResolver.NoMatchBehavior.RETURN_EMPTY_DATA,
      /* pass some prepared SortedMap<String, byte[]> */));
  ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
  return b.parse(bais);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your "count == -1" condition needs to become "count <= 0" ?

Comment: No, as I mentioned, reading is not the problem. BTW, reading from a stream or a reader and getting count of **zero** does **not** imply the end of a stream, but `-1` **do**.